# Start new career for Band Hero on Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, band-hero

I am borrowing a friend's Wii with their Band Hero game, but it has their name as the "player", and they have unlocked everything in career mode. Is there a way to create my own career without wiping their data, so I can load their user back when I return the Wii? Will this wipe all the records/scores?

I tried creating a new rock star, but that just creates one for the current player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Guitar Hero/Band Hero don't have a way of having a separate career for different players. The only thing you could do is back up the save and create a new one, but Band Hero's save is probably copy protected.

Comment: Thanks. I can not believe your can't do this easily. It seems crazy to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to [create a new Mii](http://www.ehow.com/how_2053825_create-mii-nintendo-wii.html) instead of a new game character.

Comment: but then what? What do you do with your newly created Mii? I think this is halfway there!